# Comparing two fields using FieldInfo.GetValue without knowing the MemberType

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

Given the name of a field that exists on a class (public) and not knowing the field type, is it possible to compare this field on an instance of the class to the same field on another instance of the same class?  I'm trying to do this for a "ValueHasChanged" function, something like the following:

```
Protected Function ValueHasChanged(ByVal fieldName as String) As Boolean
    Dim presentFieldInfo = presentInstance.GetType().GetField(fieldName)
    Dim originalFieldInfo = originalInstance.GetType().GetField(fieldName)
    Return presentFieldInfo.GetValue(presentInstance) <> originalFieldInfo.GetValue(originalInstance)
End Function
```

The `Return` line spawns a compiler error about not being able to compare operands of type `Object` for operator '=', which makes sense, of course.  Is there a way I can cast the values or do this differently without having to test the field's type and write a long switch/if...elseif statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply using the [System.Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) (once you've checked for Nothing) ? This won't work for some types, but many types overload the Equals method.

Comment: Yeesh, I should have thought of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try .Equals function, which is a member of Object, and returns true or false whether both are equal or not.
Of course, the underlying object has to implement Equals the right way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals(v=VS.90).aspx